# How to organise a fully flexible one-way car rental in Europe?

Tags: europe, car-rentals, one-way

Our travel plans are very flexible, so we'd like to rent a car in Geneva, then return it to an unspecified location at an unspecified date.

That is, we won't know the return city or end date at the time we take out the rental.

Are there any companies which will allow this? All of the car rental search engines I've seen require the Pick Up and Return addresses and dates up-front.

Comment: You may try to contact a car rental in France (e.g. at the French exit of Geneva Airport). Because of abuse on car insurances, one car (with foreign plates) cannot be rented on an other country, but EU has some less restriction (inside EU).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Large car hire companies offer this… but do not describe it exactly in the way you do. Specifically, you can always call them to extend the contract, add new options, etc. In effect, the return date and address are mostly used to calculate the price.

I am regularly using Avis and their FAQ explicitly mentions all this. If you exceed some maximum rental period or the car reaches its “end of life” limit, they will point you to the nearest branch (not necessarily the starting point or planned return address) to exchange it.

What they cannot do however is tell you beforehand exactly how much it will cost you (my guess is that it won't be cheap). Which makes sense.

Comment: @dan1111 As I said, it's [in the FAQ](https://www.avis.fr/faq), linking to a specific question directly is a pain, look for the word “durée”. There is also a couple of other questions on changing reservations. Obviously, you have to call them, not simply omit to show up. Did you downvote my answer?

Comment: @dan1111 I mean reading the whole thing. You can basically change any aspect of the reservation, this FAQ is very clear about that, as are the other related questions. Under what scenario do you think the OP would face “penalties”? He calls them and they tell him “no way, return the car or else…”? That's not the way it works, what they will do instead is charge a fee, as the FAQ on changing a reservation and my answer already explain.

Comment: By contrast the part of the T&C you mention is about not returning the car at all *without the consent of Avis* and does not seem very relevant. Also, asking for help to find the relevant FAQ is fine, down voting immediately, not so much.

Comment: @dan1111 And I don't think so, do *you* have any evidence for this? In fact, the FAQ clearly cover this, several questions mention “additional services” and that's what a one-way rental is, very simply.

Comment: @Relaxed You are correct for all practical purposes.  The downvote is unwarranted (not my Answer so I can say that without violating parole ;).  Upvoted.

Comment: @dan1111 Relaxed is correct.  I've changed the contract a number of times and the only notable consequence is the (sometimes) addition of a One Way Charge.  There is no practical way they can force you to return the car to a specific location, they'll just charge you more for doing so.

Comment: @dan1111 Is changing drop-off location forbidden somewhere in FAQ or rental terms? I don't think so. And non-existence of explicit allowance doesn't mean it's forbidden.  I changed once my drop-off location just calling Avis (it was in Portugal though) and asking how much would it cast.

Comment: @Relaxed You might also point out that the Render *may* have to change the car after some maximum rental period.  I've had to do this as well.

Comment: @Johns-305 Yes, that's what I was trying to explain in the second paragraph, I will try to clarify that.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about this.

Comment: My experience in the US, and I would assume US companies operating in Europe will operate the same way, has been that you can just call and extend the term and the extension is charged at the same per-day rate. Returning at a different location than where you pick the car up usually costs extra.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that your rental company might restrict the countries to which you can take. If I remember correctly, going out of the EU is usually not allowed.

Comment: @ventsyv It's a bit random, the same company, say Avis, might let you take a car rented in France to Croatia but not allow the same with a car rented in the Netherlands. I am not sure whether being allowed to take the car to a country necessarily mean you can drop it off there. It's certainly something to be mindful of.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you’d be allowed to return a left-hand drive car to a rental location in the UK, Ireland, Malta or Cyprus, which all drive on the left.

Comment: @ventsyv I've also had car rentals where they didn't allow you to take it out of country. Even inside the EU (e.g. Portugal and not allowed to go to Spain).

Comment: Most big companies in spain (hertz, avis, europcar) and europe  won't allow you to cross the country border without notice, because the insurance is paid beforehand, and most insurances only cover national grounds. when we rent vans to go to france for medieval stuff, we're charged 100€ extra as average to extend the insurance internationally.

Comment: @CptEric That's not been my experience in the north of Europe. Some companies ask for a list of country you intend to visit, some do not require any notice, I have never been charged. I have used both Europcar and Avis but I never hired a car in Spain.

Comment: @Relaxed in france, spain, portugal and italy, i've always been asked to clear where i'm going to travel (nationally or internationally), and, in the case of international, i've been forced to pay more  beforehand due to increased insurance costs.

Comment: @CptEric Like I said, I have never hired a car in Spain and I imagine the conditions may vary but in the Netherlands, I never had to pay extra and the Avis FAQ suggests it's the same for France for example. It might also depend on the class of vehicle, luxury cars often have more restrictions.

Answer (score 5):

@relaxed's answer proved to be correct, and I was able to phone up and change the drop-off location easily. The cost was calculated at the time of drop-off based on the miles driven, duration of the hire, etc.

But since I mentioned Geneva in the question it's worth pointing out that while I was free to drive the car into other countries, I had to *drop the car off within Switzerland*.

(I believe this is because of country-specific requirements like the Swiss toll sticker, and the fact that snow-rated tyres are required within Switzerland over winter, so the car company doesn't allow you to drop the vehicle off in another country.)

[image]